# Add Facebook json feed to a MySQL db

Tags: mysql, facebook, api

I guess this is a big ask. Using PHP I grab this Facebook Graph API json feed [json feed link](https://graph.facebook.com/10369058551/posts&access_token=AAACEdEose0cBAOncLas7ZC0vYOeEZAGFVlokAZAdwZAPbBz3kppF4Q02NiJC1JKHRb4ZBvcMbw3mvAXMm5Mod4X2MWGh3zRJGTrQoPxPciAZDZD)

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "10369058551_10150645263758552",
         "from": {
            "name": "Land Rover",
            "category": "Cars",
            "id": "10369058551"
         },
         "message": "This week's Land Rover photo of the week is by Rodrigo Beja. Don't forget to submit your best photos each week to get featured.",
         "link": "http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10150645263678552&set=a.443106273551.221975.10369058551&type=1",
         "icon": "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yz/r/StEh3RhPvjk.gif",
         "actions": [
            {
               "name": "Comment",
               "link": "http://www.facebook.com/10369058551/posts/10150645263758552"
            },
            {
               "name": "Like",
               "link": "http://www.facebook.com/10369058551/posts/10150645263758552"
            }
         ],
         "privacy": {
            "description": "United Kingdom",
            "value": "CUSTOM"
         },
         "type": "photo",
         "object_id": "10150645263678552",
         "created_time": "2012-02-03T17:19:03+0000",
         "updated_time": "2012-02-03T22:32:28+0000",
         "likes": {
            "data": [
               {
                  "name": "Mandy Elder",
                  "id": "100000250758731"
               }
            ],
            "count": 85
         },
         "comments": {
            "data": [
               {
                  "id": "10369058551_10150645263758552_6835532",
                  "from": {
                     "name": "John Sharp",
                     "id": "652940638"
                  },
                  "message": "This photo was used as part of the g4 challenge publicity photo pack around 2005-6 \nI remember because at the time I used it as a profile pic on msn \n\nAwesome photo - sums it up perfectly - I love it!!",
                  "created_time": "2012-02-03T21:39:48+0000"
               },
               {
                  "id": "10369058551_10150645263758552_6835852",
                  "from": {
                     "name": "Kathryn Piddington",
                     "id": "777370532"
                  },
                  "message": "Mud is good for the soul :)",
                  "created_time": "2012-02-03T22:32:28+0000"
               }
            ],
            "count": 14
         }
      },
      {
         "id": "10369058551_355476307803889",
         "from": {
            "name": "Land Rover",
            "category": "Cars",
            "id": "10369058551"
         },
         "message": "Click below to watch the new Range Rover Sport advert and catch up on the latest Land Rover and Range Rover news in this week\u2019s round-up. ",
         "picture": "http://external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQAx7xz602rfhyIn&w=90&h=90&url=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fblog.landrover.com\u00252Fwp-content\u00252Fuploads\u00252F12my_rrs_044_LowRes.jpg",
         "link": "http://blog.landrover.com/vehicles/the-land-rover-and-range-rover-weekly-19-3578.html#axzz1lKthI4F1",
         "name": "The Land Rover and Range Rover Weekly 19 | Land Rover Blog",
         "caption": "blog.landrover.com",
         "description": "In this week\u2019s round-up of all things Land Rover and Range Rover, the new Range Rover Sport advert, Which? figures reveal  the running costs of the Range Rover Evoque in comparison with competitors and a history of Land Rover narrated by Ranulph Fiennes.",
         "icon": "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yD/r/aS8ecmYRys0.gif",
         "actions": [
            {
               "name": "Comment",
               "link": "http://www.facebook.com/10369058551/posts/355476307803889"
            },
            {
               "name": "Like",
               "link": "http://www.facebook.com/10369058551/posts/355476307803889"
            }
         ],
         "privacy": {
            "description": "United Kingdom",
            "value": "CUSTOM"
         },
         "type": "link",
         "created_time": "2012-02-03T16:44:42+0000",
         "updated_time": "2012-02-03T16:44:42+0000",
         "likes": {
            "data": [
               {
                  "name": "Steve Nesbitt",
                  "id": "533982936"
               }
            ],
            "count": 10
         },
         "comments": {
            "count": 0
         }
      },
      {
         "id": "10369058551_10150642499593552",
```

I'd like to the top level items to a mysql table, then each sub level to anaother table keeping a key / link between each table and then any sub level of a sublevel and linking this too. Is this possible?

I have got as far as this:-

```
    $page = file_get_contents($url);
    $json_output = json_decode($page, true);
```

I can't figure out how to loot hrough each row and add teh data to a Mysql table.

Thanks for your help in advance

Jonathan

Comment: I would be careful as to what information your app stores in a database as the Facebook policy (http://developers.facebook.com/policy/) is pretty strict.

Answer (score 0):

Try to loop it as array then make sql query. Each array you put a unique key (for top level item). So, you can use your top level key to sub level foreign key..

Comment: Can you provide an example please? I have this so far which works for the top level array but not for the sub level arrays foreach($json_output['data'] as $key => $val) {

$dadded = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());
 // echo $val['id']."<br />";
 $pageid = '118719108161146';
 $pid = mysql_real_escape_string($val['id']);